# Verify the divergence theorem on a ball?

Tags: calculus

[image]

When I verify the divergence theorem on the ball.

I got $div(F)=1$, so $\int_{B_R(0)}div(F)dx$ is the volume of the ball, which is $\frac{4 \pi R^3}{3}$.

And $n=(x,y,z)/R$, so $\int_{\partial B_R(0)}<F,n>ds=\frac{1}{R}\int_{B_R(0)}(x^2+y) dxdy=\frac{1}{R}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R (r^3cos^2 \theta+r^2sin\theta) dr d\theta=\pi R^2/4$.

So it doesn't satisfy the divergence theorem. Where did I go wrong? Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: You have used a parametrization of a circle ($x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$). But you should have used a parametrization of the sphere (the boundary of the ball), which is $x=R\cos\theta\sin\phi$, $y=R\sin\theta\sin\phi$, with area element $R^2\sin\phi d\theta d\phi$.